# FabricJS Draw Line But...?

Tags: javascript, drawing, line, fabricjs, point

I want to do something. Example, I will put a point when I click on the screen. After When I click somewhere else to put point there. Finally, automatic line to be drawn between these two points. How do I do this?

Thank you for your help:)

Comment: Welcome to SO, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, edit your answer and add your current (broken, thats ok) solution, we will help you, but no one will write whole solution for you. This way StackOverflow works - helping throught bumps, not working instead of you.

Comment: Do not you answer (!)

Comment: Yes, i do not answer your question. I wrote only comment - i am trying to help you to better form your question to attract professionals to your case. But you are not asking for help, you are asking for solution.

Comment: I thought incorrect. You're right, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="c" height="200" width="300"></canvas>
```

**JS**

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var point1;
canvas.on('mouse:down', function (options) {

    var x = options.e.clientX - canvas._offset.left;
    var y = options.e.clientY - canvas._offset.top;

    var circle = new fabric.Circle({
        left: x,
        top: y,
        fill: 'red',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        hasControls: false,
        hasBorders: false,
        lockMovementX: true,
        lockMovementY: true,
        radius: 5,
        hoverCursor: 'default'
    });

    canvas.add(circle);

    if (point1 === undefined) {
        point1 = new fabric.Point(x, y)
    } else {
        canvas.add(new fabric.Line([point1.x, point1.y, x, y], {
            stroke: 'blue',
            hasControls: false,
            hasBorders: false,
            lockMovementX: true,
            lockMovementY: true,
            hoverCursor: 'default'
        }))
        point1 = undefined;
    }
});
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zdaax418/

Comment: Combines all the points and zoomIn, zoomOut and merge first point with last point.  -->         https://jsfiddle.net/excalibur94/mu3f8k81/

Answer (score 0):

Solution;

**HTML**

```
<button id="end">End</button>
<button id="zoomIn">Zoom-In</button>
<button id="zoomOut">Zoom-Out</button>
<canvas id="c" width="1800" height="910" ></canvas>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var point1;
var line=null;
var canvasScale = 1;
var SCALE_FACTOR = 1.2;
var bool = true;
canvas.on('mouse:down', function (options) {

    var x = options.e.clientX - canvas._offset.left;
    var y = options.e.clientY - canvas._offset.top;


    var circle = new fabric.Circle({
        left: x,
        top: y,
        fill: 'red',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        hasControls: false,
        hasBorders: false,
        lockMovementX: false,
        lockMovementY: false,
        radius: 5,
        hoverCursor: 'default'
    });

    if(bool) {
        circle.line1 = null;
        circle.line2 = null;
        canvas.add(circle);
    }   

    point1 = new fabric.Point(x, y);
    if(line){
        line = new fabric.Line([line.get('x2'), line.get('y2'), x, y], {
            fill: 'grey',
            stroke: 'grey',
            hasControls: false,
            hasBorders: false,
            lockMovementX: true,
            lockMovementY: true,
            selectable: false,
            hoverCursor: 'default'
        });
    }else{
        line = new fabric.Line([x, y, x, y], {
            fill: 'grey',
            stroke: 'grey',
            hasControls: false,
            hasBorders: false,
            lockMovementX: true,
            lockMovementY: true,
            selectable: false,
            hoverCursor: 'default'
        });
    }
    if(bool)
        canvas.add(line);
});
$("#end").click(function(){
        var lines = canvas.getObjects('line');
        var firstLine = lines[1];
        var lastLine = lines[lines.length - 1];
        line = new fabric.Line([lastLine.get('x2'), lastLine.get('y2'),firstLine.get('x1'), firstLine.get('y1')], {
            fill: 'grey',
            stroke: 'grey',
            hasControls: false,
            hasBorders: false,
            lockMovementX: false,
            lockMovementY: false,
            selectable: false,
            hoverCursor: 'default'
        });
        canvas.add(line);
        var lines = canvas.getObjects('line');
        var circles = canvas.getObjects('circle');

        for(i = 1; i < circles.length - 1; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
                if(circles[i].getLeft() == lines[j].get('x1') && circles[i].getTop() == lines[j].get('y1')) {
                    circles[i].line2 = lines[j];
                    circles[i].line1 = lines[j - 1];
                }
            }
        }
        circles[0].line1 = lines[lines.length - 1];
        circles[0].line2 = lines[1];
        circles[circles.length - 1].line2 = lines[lines.length - 1];
        circles[circles.length - 1].line1 = lines[0];

        bool = false;
    });

$("#zoomIn").click(function() {

    canvasScale = canvasScale * SCALE_FACTOR;

    canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * SCALE_FACTOR);
    canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * SCALE_FACTOR);

    var circles = canvas.getObjects('circle');

    for (var i in circles) {
        var scaleX = circles[i].scaleX;
        var scaleY = circles[i].scaleY;
        var left = circles[i].left;
        var top = circles[i].top;

        circles[i].scaleX = scaleX * SCALE_FACTOR;
        circles[i].scaleY = scaleY * SCALE_FACTOR;
        circles[i].left = left * SCALE_FACTOR;
        circles[i].top = top * SCALE_FACTOR;
        circles[i].setCoords();

        var coord = circles[i].getCenterPoint();
        circles[i].line1.set({
        'x2': coord.x,
        'y2': coord.y
        });
        circles[i].line2.set({
        'x1': coord.x,
        'y1': coord.y
        });

    }

    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.calcOffset(); 
});

$("#zoomOut").click(function() {

    canvasScale = canvasScale / SCALE_FACTOR;

    canvas.setHeight(canvas.getHeight() * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR));
    canvas.setWidth(canvas.getWidth() * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR));

    var circles = canvas.getObjects('circle');
    for (var i in circles) {
        var scaleX = circles[i].scaleX;
        var scaleY = circles[i].scaleY;
        var left = circles[i].left;
        var top = circles[i].top;

        circles[i].scaleX = scaleX * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR);
        circles[i].scaleY = scaleY * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR);
        circles[i].left = left * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR);
        circles[i].top = top * (1 / SCALE_FACTOR);

        circles[i].setCoords();
        var coord = circles[i].getCenterPoint();
        circles[i].line1.set({
        'x2': coord.x,
        'y2': coord.y
        });
        circles[i].line2.set({
        'x1': coord.x,
        'y1': coord.y
        });

    }

    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.calcOffset();    
});

canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
    var p = e.target;
    var coord = p.getCenterPoint();

    p.line1.set({ 'x2': coord.x, 'y2': coord.y });
    p.line2.set({ 'x1': coord.x, 'y1': coord.y });
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
```

Comment: you shouldn't be unaccepting an answer to post your solution with additional enhancements. I think the right way would be add a separate question detailing what you are adding and add it to that. Cheers!